# How to send verification email and block unverified with Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase auth with email and password, so no external Id providers.

The behavior I'd like:

1. Only users with a certain email domain can register. I'll call it 'domain'.
2. On registration, users receive a verification email.
3. Every time a user tries to sign in with an unverified email, he receives a verification email.
4. Access should be blocked until the email is verified.

This is what I assume happens on registration:

1. beforeCreate() fires only once just before the user is created and never again for that user. It throws an error if the domain is not "@domain.com", and falls through otherwise. This function seems to work ok.
2. beforeSignIn() fires right after beforeCreate(). Because the email is not verified at this point, the user should get a verification email. The problem is the code doesn't send the email.

I get this error from beforeSignIn():
"Unhandled error FirebaseAuthError: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier."
Because the user is not created. If I move the "send email" code snippet to beforeCreate(), the user gets created but still I get the same "no user record" error from beforeCreate().

Please advise.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.beforeCreate = functions.auth.user().beforeCreate((user, context) => {
  if (!user?.email?.includes('@domain.com')) {
    throw new functions.auth.HttpsError(
      'invalid-argument', 'Unauthorized email');
  }
});

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.beforeSignIn = functions.auth.user().beforeSignIn((user, context) => {
  if (user.email && !user.emailVerified) {
    // Send custom email verification on sign-up.
    const locale = context.locale;
      return admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(user.email).then((link) => {
        return sendCustomVerificationEmail(user.email, link, locale);
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing `!context.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`. If you look at the answer that I provided below you'll see that you don't need this. All you need to know is `!user.emailVerified` -- regardless of whether they're a new user or not -- because those are users that you want to deny access to in your `beforeSignIn` function. Additionally, it's polite to respond with a comment to the people that have taken the time to answer your question when you decide to alter your original question with new information.

Comment: @anothermh Thanks for the answer and the comment. Sorry I didn't write a comment before, it simply slipped my mind. I'm using the answer you provided but can't get past this "There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier". I don't know why, since the user is created in the auth database normally.

Comment: Please write out step-by-step what is happening. e.g., user creates account, beforeCreate fires, beforeCreate logs X error, beforeSignIn fires, beforeSignIn logs Y error. And please include the exact code that you're running that generates those logs (because I see your code has changed here). Make sure you describe alongside all of that what you expect to happen and what you are observing is happening instead. I believe that the problem is not with how the functions work but how you expect them to work and that this is just a misunderstanding.

Comment: @anothermh I overhauled the question to be clearer and added the code from my latest experiments.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** People lose a lot of time trying to implement this commonly sought-after flow. As I mentioned, it is *not* possible to generate the link before the first sign-in (the one that happens simultaneously with the sign-up) is executed.

If you use the OG email/password provider (not passwordless), the only way is to sign the user out right after registration. Since this is client side code (can be altered by anyone), you have to protect your resources as well by checking if the email is verified with every request.

I recently made an [Ultimate Guide to User Authorization with Identity Platform](https://dev.to/michalmoravik/ultimate-guide-to-user-authorization-with-identity-platform-5ekg) where I go in depth on how to implement this. You can see the sign out in [this section](https://dev.to/michalmoravik/ultimate-guide-to-user-authorization-with-identity-platform-5ekg#react-next-client-2) and how to protect your data (checking `email_verified == true`) in the [Protect Data](https://dev.to/michalmoravik/ultimate-guide-to-user-authorization-with-identity-platform-5ekg#protect-data) section. You can either use Firebase rules or a middleware in your backend.

---

I noticed the same bug yesterday. I get the same error when calling `generateEmailVerificationLink` in beforeSignIn function. It is quite silly how this Google-grade auth can be so broken.

I wrote yet another StackOverflow question on this issue. I go more in depth with explanation: [Blocking functions are broken and unable to prevent sign-in before verifying email address (Google Identity Platform & Firebase Auth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76703779/blocking-functions-are-broken-and-unable-to-prevent-sign-in-before-verifying-ema)

I don't think you can fix this with your current approach of having blocking functions for generating the verification email here.

EDIT: I just wanted to add that the only approach I can find at this moment is sending the email after creation **and** sign-in and check for `email_verified` claim every time there is a request to the backend (either by using rules for Firestore or using admin SDK for your custom server routes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [a `beforeCreate` blocking function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/auth-blocking-events#register_a_blocking_function) to manage users prior to their accounts being created:

> **[Requiring email verification on registration](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/blocking-functions#requiring_email_verification_on_registration)**
>
> The following example shows how to require a user to verify their email after registering:

```js
exports.beforeCreate = authClient.functions().beforeCreateHandler((user, context) => {
  const locale = context.locale;
  if (user.email && !user.emailVerified) {
    // Send custom email verification on sign-up.
    return admin.auth().generateEmailVerificationLink(user.email).then((link) => {
      return sendCustomVerificationEmail(user.email, link, locale);
    });
  }
});

exports.beforeSignIn = authClient.functions().beforeSignInHandler((user, context) => {
 if (user.email && !user.emailVerified) {
   throw new gcipCloudFunctions.https.HttpsError(
     'invalid-argument', `"${user.email}" needs to be verified before access is granted.`);
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not work at all. generateEmailVerificationLink returns the same error in both beforeCreateHandler as well as beforeSignInHandler. The documentation here is incorrect. I just made a question where I go more in depth: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76703779/blocking-functions-are-broken-and-unable-to-prevent-sign-in-before-verifying-ema